# Can't build Go application in GoClipse

Tags: eclipse, go

I have a simple Go program, a basic hello world copied from a tutorial somewhere. I am using Eclipse with the GoClipse functionality added.  If I right click on the folder the application is in, and run it as a Go application it works.  If I go to the command prompt and type either `go run` or `go build` it works, either for the specific file with the main program or the outside directory.

However if I try to build the project I get the error:

```
# golang.org/x/tools/cmd/splitdwarf
runtime.main_mainÂ·f: function main is undeclared in the main package
```

My program is:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() { fmt.Println("Hello World")  }
```

The directory structure is:

```
$GOPATH/src/foo/bar.go
```

`GOPATH` is `C:\goSpace` and `GOROOT` is `C:\Go

Comment: There was an answer and comments before, where did they go?

Comment: Use Goland: https://www.jetbrains.com/go/